# Why is this UILabel not showing in SKScene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uilabel

I'm trying to add a `UILabel` to a `SpriteKitView` but it won't show up.

I've set up the `UILabel` as a property of the `SKview` in .h file like this:

```
@interface LnbScene : SKScene

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *teidealTitle;

@end
```

Then in the implementation file I have tried to initialize the label in both the initWithSize method and the didMoveToView method with the following code: (neither works )

```
-(id) initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    NSLog(@"LnbScene");
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:38.0f/255.0f green:42.0f/255.0f blue:46.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(120, 300, 500, 100);
    _teidealTitle= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];


    NSString *labelText = @"LÍON NA BEARNAÍ";
    [_teidealTitle setText:labelText];
    [_teidealTitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_teidealTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:NULL size:23]];
    [_teidealTitle setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [_teidealTitle setNumberOfLines:0];

}
return self;
```

}

I did also try looking at `SKLabelNode` instead but didn't have any luck with that either.

Any pointers most welcome.

Comment: You need to add the label to the view. BTW, I suggest you use an `SKLabelNode` instead, since it is automatically removed from the scene when you transition scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use somewhere

```
[self.view addSubview: _teidealTitle];
```

With this code you will put the label in the specific view.